# No Facebook option in my Dragonvale App

Tags: dragonvale

My Dragonvale App does not have a "Facebook" option in the option menu.  I have updated the app but still nothing. Where can I find it ?

Comment: is this for iOS or Android or... ?

Answer (score 1):

That i know of there is no option for Facebook on Dragonvale. I have played the game for a while now but recently switched to a different game.